# What is math applied when measuring the fuel efficiency in cars?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, reference-request, mathematical-modeling

I have been wondering quite lately when I switched from a petrol car engine to a diesel car engine that it is much more fuel-efficient, I have a math project coming up and I wanted to take this into the further investigation, therefore, do my own measurements and modeling to compare the fuel efficiency in both cars. There will be a rate of change in the mpg when accelerating in the highway but also in the city(in other words there should be calculus), so is it a good topic to take into investigation and if you have some sources about this particular topic please let me know.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Generally, this site is used for specific math questions. Answering whether or not this is a legitimate project for a school class is not something people are going to be too fond of. As such, you might get a decent amount of downvotes for the question, and not a lot of actual responses. If you can phrase your idea into a solvable question, that would probably help your case.

Comment: I think "how would I go about comparing fuel efficiency between cars" is a very answerable math question.

Comment: So like comparing the graphs, maybe some calculus involved isn't the best? I am very interested in this topic and I'm out of topics, would you please help me with a topic that involves cars and maybe graphs and calculus?

Comment: Is maybe measuring the cooling down of a car a good example?

Comment: I took this out of reddit "Fuel efficiency is a function of (among other factors) the speed of the car. We can use mathematics to map this relationship and using it, estimate optimal speed and suggest refueling strategies." does this have calculus involved?